# Automating Manual Excel report to PowerBI

Tags: excel, vba, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm working on one customer's project in which they are using 20+ Excel reports. These Excel file fetching data from Database. There are multiple VBA macros are written in Excel files to do some manual calculations, filtering of data etc. Also each Excel workbook file contains multiple sheets. And after Excel report gets ready, they send it over an email.

Now customer wanted to do all this process in PowerBI. All Excel files with VBA macros should get converted to PowerBI reports. How we can achieve this? How we can add excel VBA macro codes to PowerBI reports ? Did anyone go through the similar tasks ?

Comment: You can't just add VBA macros to Power BI. You need to hand-migrate that logic either to Power BI or into the database. I suggest that migrating it to the database is the proper long term enterprise grade solution, assuming all the data is available.

Comment: There are lot of macro codes in all Excel files. Is there any other way ? Can we migrate the macro code/logic to SSIS packages ?

Comment: Any form of "lift and shift" that preserves the VBA would make the migration redundant. You'd still have all of your existing issue. VBA is for automating interactive office applications. It's not reliable to use it to automate office apps behind the scenes

Comment: Sounds familiar. And in the end the customer probably wants to have all the results back in Excel because this is what he's used to ...